# carousel using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, carousel

I know there are plugins available out there, but I'm trying to make one of myself but before that I'm trying to understand the concept of making it as an infinite/circular carousel. Here is my [jsfiddle so far..](http://jsfiddle.net/hbk35/KPKyz/1/)  http://jsfiddle.net/hbk35/KPKyz/3/

HTML:

```
    <div id="carousel_wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div>0</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>1</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>2</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>3</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>4</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>5</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>6</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>7</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<br>
<div id="buttons">
    <button id="left">left</button>
    <button id="right">right</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var container = $("#carousel_wrapper");

var runner = container.find('ul');
var liWidth = runner.find('li:first').outerWidth();
var itemsPerPage = 3;
var noofitems = runner.find('li').length;

runner.width(noofitems * liWidth);
container.width(itemsPerPage*liWidth);

$('#right').on('click',function(){
   runner.animate({scrollLeft: -liWidth},1000);
});


$('#left').on('click',function(){
    runner.animate({scrollLeft: liWidth},1000);
});
```

CSS:

```
div#carousel_wrapper{

    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}

ul {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
ul li {
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
}
ul li div {
    border:1px solid white;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:gray;
}
```

I do not want to use clone and detach method. Is there any other way to do that?
Please anyone would like to guide me where I'm making mistake. I'm newbie to stack overflow and javascript/jquery also..trying to learn on my own. Forgive me I'm trying since to put my code onto the question, couldn't get neat and separate like others.

Thanks!!

Comment: We need a `reinventing-the-wheel` tag on SO

Comment: The code in the fiddle doesn't match the code in your question.

Comment: @j08691 my apologies. the fiddle is updated. thanks.

Comment: Are you looking to implement the carousel from jquery framework or any other framework

Comment: @Someone using jQuery framework. actually I'm trying to make plugin of it. and to make it circular/infinite.

Comment: I hope you figured it out! This is unrelated to the question, but before you use it I would recommend reading this: http://shouldiuseacarousel.com/

Comment: @Dryden Long people are sometime need the custom one. Not all of the available wheels out there can satisfy the needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go an infinite. Could be done with less code for sure.
http://jsfiddle.net/artuc/rGLsG/3/

**HTML:**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btnPrevious">Previous</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btnNext">Next</a>
<div class="carousel">
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>8</li>
        <li>9</li>
        <li>10</li>
        <li>11</li>
        <li>12</li>
        <li>13</li>
        <li>14</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.carousel{
        padding-top: 20px;
        width: 357px;
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 50px;
        position: relative;
    }.carousel ul{
        position: relative;
        list-style: none;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        height: 50px;
        padding: 0;
    }.carousel ul li{
        position: absolute;
        height: 25px;
        width: 50px;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 1px;
        background: #f2f2f2;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 25px;
    }
```

**JS:**

```
$(function(){
        var carousel = $('.carousel ul');
        var carouselChild = carousel.find('li');
        var clickCount = 0;
        var canClick = true;

        itemWidth = carousel.find('li:first').width()+1; //Including margin

        //Set Carousel width so it won't wrap
        carousel.width(itemWidth*carouselChild.length);

        //Place the child elements to their original locations.
        refreshChildPosition();

        //Set the event handlers for buttons.
        $('.btnNext').click(function(){
            if(canClick){
                canClick = false;
                clickCount++;

                //Animate the slider to left as item width 
                carousel.stop(false, true).animate({
                    left : '-='+itemWidth
                },300, function(){
                    //Find the first item and append it as the last item.
                    lastItem = carousel.find('li:first');
                    lastItem.remove().appendTo(carousel);
                    lastItem.css('left', ((carouselChild.length-1)*(itemWidth))+(clickCount*itemWidth));
                    canClick = true;
                });
            }
        });

        $('.btnPrevious').click(function(){
            if(canClick){
                canClick = false;
                clickCount--;
                //Find the first item and append it as the last item.
                lastItem = carousel.find('li:last');
                lastItem.remove().prependTo(carousel);

                lastItem.css('left', itemWidth*clickCount);             
                //Animate the slider to right as item width 
                carousel.finish(true).animate({
                    left: '+='+itemWidth
                },300, function(){
                    canClick = true;
                });
            }
        });

        function refreshChildPosition(){
            carouselChild.each(function(){
                $(this).css('left', itemWidth*carouselChild.index($(this)));
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: There was a bug when you fast click. Added finish() method to JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/artuc/rGLsG/2/

Comment: works like a charm! awesome this is what i was looking for... thanks!! but theres a small issue with it.. if you keep pressing next button, you will find an space between 1&2 li elements.

Comment: Yep, neither animate nor finish seems to work if you click really fast. I implemented a dirty solution to it. Please see the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/artuc/rGLsG/3/ also removed one useless function.

Comment: yeah i see the problem with your updated fiddle. if u click left continuously and fast, u will see the first element not there + some random space in between. else previous button works awesome!! thanks though!

Comment: i think if we can fix the random space issue!

Comment: @hbk35 have you checked the latest version? http://jsfiddle.net/artuc/rGLsG/5/ I tried with chrome and ff it doesn't matter how fast i click, i don't get any random space. Actually it wasn't space items were overlapping each other. And after the first click it was fixing it self. Anyway, it's fixed and i believe it's good to go :)

Answer (score 3):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/KPKyz/5/

**JS**

```
var container = $("#carousel_wrapper");

var runner = container.find('ul');
var liWidth = runner.find('li:first').outerWidth();
var itemsPerPage = 3;
var noofitems = runner.find('li').length;

runner.width(noofitems * liWidth);
container.width(itemsPerPage*liWidth);

$('#right').click(function() {
    $( runner  ).animate({ "left": "-=51px" }, "slow" );
});


$('#left').click(function() {
    $( runner  ).animate({ "left": "+=51px" }, "slow" );
});
```

**CSS**

```
div#carousel_wrapper{

 overflow:hidden;
 position:relative;
 width:500px;
 height: 100px;
}

ul {
 padding:0px;
 margin:0px;
 position: absolute;
 top:50px;
 left: 0px;
 width:300px;
 height: 50px;
 overflow: hidden;
 }
 ul li {
   list-style:none;
  float:left;
 }
ul li div {
  border:1px solid white;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:gray;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, was looking for something like that without additinoal plugins

Comment: Oh..I thought you were OP :P ...My bad

Comment: @Ani thats awesome. two more question. why i cannot use liWidth if I'm not aware of the width? how can i make it circular/infinite?? appreciate it.

Comment: Oh...I didn't knew you want circular...hold on