# jQuery carousel - disable next/previous link when last item on the list is reached

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I'm very new with jQuery and what I did is just I followed what's been done here:

[carousel using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22078356/carousel-using-jquery)

But I just want to ask, what if I want to slide to the last item and then disable the links indicating that the last item has been reached so we just have to stop sliding? Please help, I really need to not have infinite slide.

Here's my code

```
$(function(){
    var carousel = $('.carousel ul');
    var carouselChild = carousel.find('li');
    var clickCount = 0;
    var canClick = true;

    itemWidth = carousel.find('li:first').width()+1; //Including margin

    //Set Carousel width so it won't wrap
    carousel.width(itemWidth*carouselChild.length);

    //Place the child elements to their original locations.
    refreshChildPosition();

    //Set the event handlers for buttons.
    $('.btnNext').click(function(){
        if(canClick){
            canClick = false;
            clickCount++;

            //Animate the slider to left as item width 
            carousel.stop(false, true).animate({
                left : '-='+itemWidth
            },300, function(){
                //Find the first item and append it as the last item.
                lastItem = carousel.find('li:first');
                lastItem.remove().appendTo(carousel);
                lastItem.css('left', ((carouselChild.length-1)*(itemWidth))+(clickCount*itemWidth));
                canClick = true;
            });
        }
    });

    $('.btnPrevious').click(function(){
        if(canClick){
            canClick = false;
            clickCount--;
            //Find the first item and append it as the last item.
            lastItem = carousel.find('li:last');
            lastItem.remove().prependTo(carousel);

            lastItem.css('left', itemWidth*clickCount);             
            //Animate the slider to right as item width 
            carousel.finish(true).animate({
                left: '+='+itemWidth
            },300, function(){
                canClick = true;
            });
        }
    });

    function refreshChildPosition(){
        carouselChild.each(function(){
            $(this).css('left', itemWidth*carouselChild.index($(this)));
        });
    }
});
```

## [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/artuc/rGLsG/5)

Comment: What's your code? JS and HTML? Add it here...

Comment: Exactly what's in this fiddle: jsfiddle.net/artuc/rGLsG/5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will just have to check the first and last `li`s for you slide window.

This will work for you:

```
$(function(){
    var carousel = $('.carousel ul');
    var carouselChild = carousel.find('li');
    var clickCount = 0;
    var canClick = true;

    itemWidth = carousel.find('li:first').width()+1; //Including margin

    //Set Carousel width so it won't wrap
    carousel.width(itemWidth*carouselChild.length);

    //Place the child elements to their original locations.
    refreshChildPosition();

    //Set the event handlers for buttons.
    $('.btnNext').click(function(e){        
        if($(".carousel").find("li:eq(6)").text()!=14) {
            if(canClick) {
                canClick = false;
                clickCount++;
                //Animate the slider to left as item width 
                carousel.stop(false, true).animate({
                    left : '-='+itemWidth
                },300, function(){
                    //Find the first item and append it as the last item.
                    lastItem = carousel.find('li:first');
                    lastItem.remove().appendTo(carousel);
                    lastItem.css('left', ((carouselChild.length-1)*(itemWidth))+(clickCount*itemWidth));
                    canClick = true;
                });
            }
        }
    });

    $('.btnPrevious').click(function(){
        if($(".carousel").find("li:eq(0)").text()!=1) {
            if(canClick){
                canClick = false;
                clickCount--;
                //Find the first item and append it as the last item.
                lastItem = carousel.find('li:last');
                lastItem.remove().prependTo(carousel);

                lastItem.css('left', itemWidth*clickCount);             
                //Animate the slider to right as item width 
                carousel.finish(true).animate({
                    left: '+='+itemWidth
                },300, function(){
                    canClick = true;
                });
            }
        }
    });

    function refreshChildPosition(){
        carouselChild.each(function(){
            $(this).css('left', itemWidth*carouselChild.index($(this)));
        });
    }
});
```

## **[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rGLsG/24/)**

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't see anything in the fiddle :(