# Scrolling/carousel with interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I try to make jQuery scrolling carousel with Previous and Next buttons without any plugin.  My code in jQuery has two parts- first one for scrolling and second one for a buttons. Maybe that is completely wrong. Now I want to set an interval for scrolling, but I have no idea how.

Here is Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/lilivasileva/rGLsG/116/

```
$(function(){
    var scroller = $('#carousel_container div.carousel');
    var scrollerContent = scroller.children('ul');
    scrollerContent.children().clone().appendTo(scrollerContent);
    var curX = 0;
    scrollerContent.children().each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.css('left', curX);
        curX += $this.outerWidth(true);
    });
    var fullW = curX / 2;
    var viewportW = scroller.width();

    var controller = {curSpeed:0, fullSpeed:1,};
    var $controller = $(controller);
    var tweenToNewSpeed = function(newSpeed, duration)
    {
        if (duration === undefined)
            duration = 800;
        $controller.stop(true).animate({curSpeed:newSpeed}, duration);
    };

    // Pause on hover
    scroller.hover(function(){
        tweenToNewSpeed(0);
    }, function(){
        tweenToNewSpeed(controller.fullSpeed);
    });

    // Scrolling management; start the automatical scrolling
    var doScroll = function()
    {
        var curX = scroller.scrollLeft();
        var newX = curX + controller.curSpeed;
        if (newX > fullW*2 - viewportW)
            newX -= fullW;
        scroller.scrollLeft(newX);
    };
    setInterval(doScroll, 80);
    tweenToNewSpeed(controller.fullSpeed);
     });



       $(function(){
      var carousel = $('.carousel ul');
     var carouselChild = carousel.find('li');
       var clickCount = 0;
      var canClick = true;

itemWidth = carousel.find('li:first').width()+1; //Including margin

//Set Carousel width so it won't wrap
carousel.width(itemWidth*carouselChild.length);

//Place the child elements to their original locations.
refreshChildPosition();

//Set the event handlers for buttons.
$('.btnNext').click(function(e){        
    if($(".carousel").find("li:eq(6)").text()!=20) {
        if(canClick) {
            canClick = false;
            clickCount++;
            //Animate the slider to left as item width 
            carousel.stop(false, true).animate({
                left : '-='+itemWidth
            },300, function(){
                //Find the first item and append it as the last item.
                lastItem = carousel.find('li:first');
                lastItem.remove().appendTo(carousel);
                lastItem.css('left', ((carouselChild.length-1)*(itemWidth))+(clickCount*itemWidth));
                canClick = true;
            });
        }
    }


});

$('.btnPrevious').click(function(){
    if($(".carousel").find("li:eq(0)").text()!=1) {
        if(canClick){
            canClick = false;
            clickCount--;
            //Find the first item and append it as the last item.
            lastItem = carousel.find('li:last');
            lastItem.remove().prependTo(carousel);

            lastItem.css('left', itemWidth*clickCount);             
            //Animate the slider to right as item width 
            carousel.finish(true).animate({
                left: '+='+itemWidth
            },300, function(){
                canClick = true;
            });
        }
    }



});

function refreshChildPosition(){
    carouselChild.each(function(){
        $(this).css('left', itemWidth*carouselChild.index($(this)));
    });
}
 });
```

Comment: you might wanna take a look on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22078356/2958224

Comment: i try to make a carousel with  pause in the scrolling animation. My buttons work ok. But I have no idea how can I make this pause.

Comment: it is pausing on hover? when you are trying to pause?

Comment: i try to make something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/c5VQe/. Carousel with interval/pause between animation.